# INSERT query error: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/WEB/App_Data/mydata.accdb");

        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("insert into player_reg (p_name,f_name,dob,pob,sex,marital,nation,address,address,state,mob,email,course,college,y_year,sports,voter) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text+ "', '" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "', '" + TextBox12.Text+ "','" + TextBox13.Text+ "', '" + TextBox14.Text + "''" + TextBox15.Text + "', '" + TextBox16.Text + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("values inserted successfully");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `adress` 2 times in your query, delete it.

OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("insert into player_reg (p_name,f_name,dob,pob,sex,marital,nation,
**address,address**,state,mob,email,course,college,
y_year,sports,voter) values ...

Answer (score 1):

There are 17 items in the columns list but only 16 items in the VALUES list. In the columns list you repeated `address` twice.

While I have your attention, constructing SQL statements by "gluing together" raw user input (`textbox.Text` values) is **very bad practice**. You should use a parameterized query instead.

```csharp
con.Open();
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(
        "insert into player_reg (p_name, f_name, dob, pob, sex, marital, nation, address, state, mob, email, course, college, y_year, sports, voter)" +
        "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text);  // p_name
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text);  // f_name
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text);  // dob
// ...and so on...
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox16.Text);  // voter
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Field address is repeated in your query -- the number of columns must be equal to number of values in "VALUES" clause separated by ','.